# Unit Testing AWS SWF Ruby Flow

Tags: amazon-swf, aws-ruby-flow

We're using the [aws-ruby-flow](https://github.com/aws/aws-flow-ruby) framework and are curious how others have unit tested their activity logic and their workflow logic? Can anyone share some sample specs? The examples given in [aws-flow-ruby-samples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-flow-ruby-samples) don't seem to have any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cross posted this to the Github project for this SDK and it was answered there: https://github.com/aws/aws-flow-ruby/issues/104#issuecomment-150633680